# Does this code fail to build because of a compiler bug?

Tags: delphi

Building, not just compiling, the following fails with an internal compiler error when using Delphi 6 if optimization is on.  Using the assignment instead of the inc() works.  Is this a compiler bug?  The weird record structures are because the original code has been reduced to this minimal example.

```
program Project1;

type
  requestCountsType = array[0..1] of
    record
    processed: int64;
    end;

  talliestype = record
    counts: requestCountsType;
    end;

  healthtype = record
    charged: talliestype;
    end;

procedure computeProcessed(const h: healthtype; var requests, bytesin, bytesout: int64);
var i: byte;
begin
requests := 0; bytesin := 0; bytesout := 0;
for i := 0 to 1 do
  begin
  inc(requests, h.charged.counts[i].processed); // including this generates compiler internal error C1405 when optimization is on
  // requests := requests + h.charged.counts[i].processed; // this works
  end;
end;

var ht: healthtype; var r, b1, b2: int64;

begin
computeProcessed(ht, r, b1, b2);
end.
```

Comment: I'd say an internal compiler error is a bug, yes. If the code wasn't valid, you would expect a proper error at least. I believe there's nothing wrong with your `inc` code. And if it works without optimizations..

Comment: Seems it doesn't like the *const* of healthtype.

Comment: 99.99% of the time, if you think it's a compiler bug, it's not. +1 for catching a real one.

Comment: Internal compiler error is, by definition a bug

Comment: @MarkRansom that figure is a little lower for early Delphi versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [bug report #109124](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109124). I can confirm the problem in Delphi XE; the bug report says it was fixed in Delphi XE4.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz It compiles in Delphi XE in 'Debug' configuration but fails in 'Release' configuration with internal error C1970. BTW I've found the bug report by googling 'internal error C1970'.

Comment: @Serge - It's my fault. Removed my comment which was wrong and +1. Sorry.

Comment: I would assume C1405 is not the same as C1970, but we'll call it close enough.